# Download `foo.tar.bz2` file from Nexus Repository Manager in Yocto build using recipe (.bb) file

Tags: nexus, yocto, recipe

I'm going to download some binaries packed in `foo.tar.bz2` from Nexus Repository Manager and making available to the yocto image.

My `.bb` file looks like:

```
SUMMARY = "Some text"
DESCRIPTION = "Some text"
LICENSE = "LGPLv2.1"

LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=xxxxxx"

SRC_URI = " \
   https://${NEXUS_USERNAME}:${NEXUS_PASSWORD}@nexus.artifacts.foo.link/repository/Applications/**/${NEXUS_VERSION}_foo.tar.bz2 \
  "

S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_install() {
  
   install -d ${D}${bindir}/
   install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/${NEXUS_VERSION}_foo.tar.bz2 ${D}${bindir}/
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
...
--progress=dot -v failed with exit code 1, output:
Fetcher failure for 
https://nexus.artifacts.xxxxx.link/repository/Applications/**/foo.tar.bz2: Bad port number.

Unable to fetch URL from any source.
```

However, when I use the link `https://${NEXUS_USERNAME}:${NEXUS_PASSWORD}@nexus.artifacts.foo.link/repository/Applications/**/${NEXUS_VERSION}_foo.tar.bz2` on browser,
I get the download prompt and after clicking the `yes` I am able to download .tar.bz2 on my host machine.

Don't know what's wrong with this approach? I just want a .tar.bz file to be downloaded that's all. Any help would be great.

Comment: You say that the url works... but '*' is not a valid character in a url. Even if it was url encoded and Nexus actually does something reasonable with it, you probably don't want to use some wildcard mapping (if that's what it is) but an actual unique url.

Comment: Hi @JussiKukkonen, thanks for your reply. Actually, I was not using the wildcard, I just tried to skip the long directory name, sorry for the confusion there. The problem in my case was in URL encoding. My username had @ character(usual in email). Once I replace this with `%40` it woked well.